# Is my proof correct? Prove MN is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on the following question:
If G is a group and M and N are normal subgroups, prove that MN={mn : $me$M and n$e$N} is a normal subgroup.

This is my uncertain proof:

Firstly: Prove MN is a subgroup
 1. To prove: MN is closed under multiplication and each element has a inverse
Let $m_1,m_2 e M$ and $n_1,n_2eN$
Then $m_1m_2 e M$  and  $n_1n_2eN$
$m_1m_2n_1n_2$$e MN$
$m_1n_1m_2n_2 e MN$ ....(As M, N are normal subgroups).... **is this step correct? I am uncertain?**
Thus MN is closed

2. To prove each element has a inverse
   Let $m_1 e M$ and $n_1eN$
   Thus $m_1^{-1} e M$  and $n_1^{-1} e N$
   $m_1^{-1}n_1^{-1} e MN$
   $(m_1n_1)^{-1} eMN$
   Thus for all $mn e MN$ there exists $(mn)^{-1}$ s.t $(mn)(mn)^{-1}=e$
   Thus each element of MN has a inverse.

MN is a subgroup of G

I think the rest of my proof is correct (to conclude MN is normal)so I will leave that out, but is the above part to prove it is a subgroup correct? I am uncertain about the step that I indicated (I know M and N is commutative, so I can swop two elements in M or two elements in N, but I think I swopped a m and n as well?). Thanks a lot . Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but it's incorrect. You're assuming that $mn=nm$, for $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, which is generally false.

Comment: Okay,that was what was bothering me. So I can only do that after proving that MN is normal, which is exactly what I am working towards? Is this correct?

Comment: Part 2 is incorrect too, since you are assuming the false identity "$(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$", instead of the correct one $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

It is not correct as written.

However, if $N$ is a *normal* subgroup and $m\in M$, $n\in N$, then
$$ mn = mn = mn(m^{-1}m) = (mnm^{-1})m = n'm $$
where $n'\in N$ too -- which is enough to make the closure step work.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect, I'm afraid.

You want to use that, for $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, there exist $m_1\in M$ and $n_1\in N$ such that $mn=n_1m_1$. This needs a proof, of course.

Note: in general you cannot choose $m_1=m$ *and* $n_1=n$.

Hint: $mn=mn1=mn(m^{-1}m)=(mnm^{-1})m$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $M\triangleleft G$ and $N\triangleleft G$, then $\forall g\in G$, we have $gM=Mg$ and $gN=Ng$, how $M\leq G$ and $N\leq G$ then $e\in N,\ M$, therefore $e=ee\in MN$, now let $x, \ y \in MN$, then there exists $m_{1},m_{2}\in M$ and $n_{1},n_{2}\in N$ such that $x=m_{1}n_{1}\mbox{ and }y=m_{2}n_{2}$, it's clear that $n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}\in G$ then $n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}M=Mn_{1}n_{2}^{-1}$, then exists $m_{3}\in M$ such that $n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}m_{2}^{-1}=m_{3}n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}$ then:

$$xy^{-1}=m_{1}n_{1}(m_{2}n_{2})^{-1}=m_{1}n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}m_{2}^{-1}=m_{1}m_{3}n_{1}n_{2}^{-1}\in MN$$

Therefore $MN\leq G$.